# Есть строка в которой хранятся значения байтов, нужно её декодировать

Tags: python-3.x, decode

Пробовал:

`s.encode().decode('utf-8')` - ничего не делает

`s.decode('utf-8')` - интерпретатор жалуется на то что s - не строка

вывод с CMD windows в строку.

Вывод примерно такой:

```
b'\x91\xe2\xe0\xe3\xaa\xe2\xe3\xe0\xa0 \xaf\xa0\xaf\xae\xaa\r\n\x91\xa5\xe0\xa8\xa9\xad\xeb\xa9 \xad\xae\xac\xa5\xe0 \xe2\xae\xac\xa0: 00610072 B4DB:884E\r\nC:.\r\n\x8f\xae\xa4\xaf\xa0\xaf\xaa\xa8 \xae\xe2\xe1\xe3\xe2\xe1\xe2\xa2\xe3\xee\xe2 \r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: Этот вывод – результат `print(s)`?

Comment: Да, это результат вывода print(s)

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

например:

```
res = text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

print(res)
```

**Нашел вашу ошибку!!!**

это не utf-8, смените кодировку:

```
res = text.decode('cp866')
```

и вот что получится:

```
Структура папок
Серийный номер тома: 00610072 B4DB:884E
C:.
Подпапки отсутствуют
```

Comment: Извините, что не в тему, но `'ignore'` вторым аргументом, это чтобы он не выкидывал бесячее исключение про character codec, когда в строку попало тире длиннее, чем ему нравится?

Comment: @V-Mor, ну в принципе да, но я привел этот пример чтобы показать, что в принципе со строкой все нормально, ее только нужно правильно обработать, и ниже уже привел решение - про кодировку стало понятно как раз после первого кода, когда он все таки выдавал значащий текст, но не весь и можно было понять, что похоже он просто не переваривает некоторые символы, дальше потребовалось просто найти нужную кодировку (попал со второй попытки, сначала cp-1251 попробовал)

Comment: Это я понял. Вы решили задачу автора, за что Вам спасибо, но ещё большее спасибо за то, что невольно подсказали вариант решения проблемы с неподдерживаемыми символами, которая мучила меня довольно давно.

Comment: "вывод с CMD windows в строку" - логично же, что это `cp866`, как я сразу то не догадался )

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'... Не работает метод decode Python 3.7.4

Comment: @TwoFools, я на 3.8.2 проверял :), обновите питон, если есть такая возможность   или используйте класс `bytes` - он предоставляет данный метод (https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)

Comment: @Zhihar, у меня в строке уже байты, а сделать s = byte(s) вроде как нельзя